# Swift format string with separator every n characters where n changes

Tags: strings, swift, formatting

In Swift I have a string where a dash needs to be inserted after every 3 characters, if there are 4 characters or 2 characters at the end of the string they should be shown as "-xx-xx" or "-xx" respectively.

```
E.g "203940399345" to "203-940-399-345"
    "2039403993454" to "203-940-399-34-54"
    "20394039934546" to "203-940-399-345-46" 
    "2039403993454699409399" to "203-940-399-345-469-940-93-99"
```

I have the following solution:

```
func format(_ unformatted:String) -> String {

  var formatted = ""
  let count = unformatted.characters.count

  unformatted.characters.enumerated().forEach {
    if $0.offset % 3 == 0 && $0.offset != 0 && $0.offset != count - 1 || $0.offset == count - 2 && count % 3 != 0 {
      formatted += "-" + String($0.element)
      return
    }
    formatted += String($0.element)
    return
  }
  return formatted
}
```

It will add a dash before each third char unless it is the first or last char or it is two from the end but only if the char count is divisible by 3 then it adds a char to the formatted string as normal.

Is there a more optimal way to achieve this formatting? What approach should I be taking with this kind of problem?

Comment: it seems you should use regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recursive approach is likely the most maintainable and flexible for this.   It can be made fully configurable and can become an extension of the String type.

For example:

```
extension String
{
   func group(by groupSize:Int=3, separator:String="-") -> String
   {
      if characters.count <= groupSize   { return self }

      let splitSize  = min(max(2,characters.count-2) , groupSize)
      let splitIndex = index(startIndex, offsetBy:splitSize)

      return substring(to:splitIndex) 
           + separator 
           + substring(from:splitIndex).group(by:groupSize, separator:separator)
   }
}

string.group(by:3)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is working fine. I don't think you can optimize your code but you can  use reduce and extend String as follow:

```
extension String {
    var customFormatted: String {
        let count = characters.count
        return characters.enumerated().reduce("") { $1.offset % 3 == 0 && $1.offset != 0 && $1.offset != count-1 || $1.offset == count-2 && count % 3 != 0 ? $0 + "-\($1.element)" : $0 + "\($1.element)" } 
    }
}
```

---

Another option you have is to use map and join the resulting array:

```
extension String {
    var customFormatted: String {
        let count = characters.count
        return characters.enumerated().map { $0.offset % 3 == 0 && $0.offset != 0 && $0.offset != count-1 || $0.offset == count-2 && count % 3 != 0 ? "-\($0.element)" : "\($0.element)" }.joined()
    }

}

"2039403993454".customFormatted    // "203-940-399-34-54"
```

Answer (score 3):

There is one small bug in your code, a two-character string is formatted with an initial dash:

```
print(format("12")) // -12
```

There are various ways to fix  that, e.g. by replacing the condition

```
$0.offset == count - 2 && count % 3 != 0
```

with

```
$0.offset == count - 2 && $0.offset % 3 == 2
```

Now some suggestions to simplify the code and make it more readable.
Instead of

```
unformatted.characters.enumerated().forEach {
     // ... use `$0.offset` and `$0.element` ...
}
```

I would use `for ... in`, so that we can give the loop variables names:

```
for (offset, char) in unformatted.characters.enumerated() {
     // ... use `offset` and `char` ...
}
```

There is no need to convert `$0.element` to a `String` because you can
append a character directly:

```
formatted.append($0.element)
```

There is also no need to call `return` at the end of the iteration block.

The condition

```
if $0.offset % 3 == 0 && $0.offset != 0 && $0.offset != count - 1 || $0.offset == count - 2 && $0.offset % 2 == 2
```

is quite complex, I would  split it into two conditions with `if`/`else if`.

Putting it all together, the function would then look like this:

```
func format(_ unformatted: String) -> String {

    var formatted = ""
    let count = unformatted.characters.count

    for (offset, char) in unformatted.characters.enumerated() {
        if offset > 0 && offset % 3 == 0 && offset != count - 1 {
            formatted.append("-")
        } else if offset % 3 == 2 && offset == count - 2 {
            formatted.append("-")
        }
        formatted.append(char)
    }

    return formatted
}
```

The condition whether to insert the separator at an offset is quite complex and
it is easy to make an error. A completely different approach would be
a recursive implementation, which is (almost) self-explaining:

```
func format(_ str: String) -> String {

    switch str.characters.count {
    case 0...3:  // No separators for strings up to length 3.
        return str
    case 4: // "abcd" -> "ab-cd"
        let idx = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)
        return str.substring(to: idx) + "-" + str.substring(from: idx)
    default: // At least 5 characters. Separate the first three and recurse:
        let idx = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)
        return str.substring(to: idx) + "-" + format(str.substring(from: idx))
    }

}
```

More suggestions:

- Choose a different name instead of `format()` which indicates the purpose of the formatting.
- Make the separator character a parameter of the function.

Comment: very good solutions. most i like the recursive solution because it becomes simple and self explaining code